# Remove spaces between line breaks only

Tags: r, regex, line-breaks, stringr

I have the following example string with line breaks "\n" and spaces " ":

`a <- "\n \n   \n \nTEST TEST\n"`

I would like to remove spaces (" ") directly following after line breaks ("\n"), but not the spaces after other strings (like "TEST" in my toy example). My desired output is therefore:

`"\n\n\n\nTEST TEST\n"`

I tried stringr's **str_remove_all** and **str_replace_all** but didn't succeed as those seem to have problems in this case with the adjacent occurences of the line breaks. This is the closest I got:

`str_replace_all(a, "\n[ ]*\n", "\n\n")`

I spent hours on this (probably ridiculously easy) problem, any help is thus highly appreciated!

Comment: It is not clear what you want to get in case of `"    \n \n   \n \n    TEST TEST\nTest1 Test2 
  \n    "` If you need a definitive answer with a reliable solution please share your current code. "I spent hours on this" - what does not work? Could you please share the regex you used? Note you say "Remove spaces between line breaks only", but the space in `TEST TEST` is also between two `\n`s, and you want it to stay. Please clarify your issue.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor for the hint, I thought it was clear as I wrote "between" line breaks (that excludes "before" and "after" line breaks). It is however not a big issue if the leading and trailing white spaces are removed as well.
I came closest trying this: str_replace_all(a, "\n[ ]*\n", "\n\n"), but that only removed the non-overlapping occurences.
LC-datascientist in the meantime solved my problem.

Comment: I thought you only wanted to remove blanks (space and tabs) from blank lines. Please edit the question with your actual attempt and real problem description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
gsub("\n *", "\n", a)
```

or

```r
str_replace_all(a, "\n *", "\n") # with stringr package
```

will get you the desired output `"\n\n\n\nTEST TEST\n"`

**EDIT: For space(s) only between blank lines**

Note that the above will also remove spaces that appear at the start of non-blank lines—e.g., if the string was `"\n TEST TEST \n"`

@[bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble)'s suggestion of including `(?=\n)` into the search pattern (i.e., `"\n *(?=\n)"`) works for between blank lines. (Thank you, [bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble))

```r
gsub("\n *(?=\n)", "\n", a, perl=TRUE)
```

or

```r
str_replace_all(a, "\n *(?=\n)", "\n") # with stringr package
```

`(?=(regex))` is a [positive lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). As `"\n *(?=\n)"`, it means that the asserted regex `\n` needs to appear directly after `\n *` (new line with blank space(s)), but it will *not* be captured in the string pattern. Because the asserted regex is not captured in the pattern, it does not get replaced when using `gsub` or `stringr::str_replace_all`.

To illustrate this more clearly, only the "b" that appears before "bu" is replaced in the following example:

```r
str_replace_all("bobblebbubble", "b(?=bu)", "_")
#[1] "bobble_bubble"
```

Comment: Note that in this case, you also remove literal space from the start of non-blank lines.

Comment: I wonder if you could use [`gsub("\n *(?=\n)", "\n", a, perl=TRUE)`](https://tio.run/##K/r/P1HBRldBSUEhJg@EoHSIa3CIAogACSlxpReXJmkoAdlaGva2MXmaSjoKQB6QTNRRKEgtyrENCQp11fz/HwA) if the spaces should be between newlines. Well, I'm not into R, just an idea.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can remove any line that consists of horizontal whitespace. With `stringr`, you can use

```r
library(stringr)
a <- "\n \n   \n \nTEST TEST\n"
stringr::str_replace_all(a, "(?m)^\\h+$", "")
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/CgzCan) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dax17F/1). *Details*:

- `(?m)` - a multiline modifier making `^` match start of any line and `$` match any end of line positions
- `^` - line start
- `\h+` - one or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `$` - line end.